# Search in Android not working

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-searchmanager

I have been struggling with search feature in android for days. Unable to pinpoint the bug.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exclude_list);

    .......

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.options_menu_main_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if(null!=searchManager ) {
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    handleIntent(getIntent());

}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        Log.i("q",query);
    }
}
```

searchable.xml

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:hint="@string/search_hint"
 android:includeInGlobalSearch="false"
 android:label="@string/app_name"
 android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search_hint" />
```

Menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/options_menu_main_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Manifest

```
<activity
 android:name="com.xyz.Exclude_list"
 android:label="@string/title_activity_exclude_list"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:launchMode="singleTop">
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 </intent-filter>

 <meta-data
  android:name="android.app.searchable"
  android:resource="@xml/searchable"
  android:value=".app.Search"
 />
</activity>
```

Error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at com.xyz.Exclude_list.onCreate(Exclude_list.java:64)
```

Line 64: `searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));`

If i remove

```
 SearchView searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.options_menu_main_search);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if(null!=searchManager ) {
      searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
```

the search is working but I am unable to fetch/Log any query when I give input in search.

Comment: what is on Line 64 `Exclude_list.java`?

Comment: `searchView` must be null. Are you sure it is in the `activity_exclude_list` layout and has the id: `options_menu_main_search`?

Comment: Do you use `ActionBarActivity` as activity extension?

Comment: @Fllo: no.Just `public class Exclude_list extends Activity{}`

Comment: searchview is a menu item that appears in the action bar. But you initialize it in Activity? You are using SearchView from the supporot library??

Comment: Put a breakpoint on that line and inspect each element.  Which one is null?

Comment: @tambykojak: Should it be present be activity_exclude_list layout? Currently ther's one TextView and one ListView in RelativeLayout.

Comment: @Raghunandan: I even tried using `android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"` but still same error.

Comment: If i remove those line, the search is working but I am unable to fetch any query when typed in search.

Comment: @curious_coder that change does not make any difference as you have a NPE. You need to initialize the search view in `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Read the same @ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: @Raghunandan: Thanks.. Unfortunately I removed the code from `onCreateOptionsMenu` because of another bug and after resolving the bug, I paste it in wrong onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize a `MenuItem` inside `onCreate` method. You should initialize it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` method as:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.options_menu_main_search).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if(null!=searchManager ) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }
}
```

See the [Using Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget) topic from Documentation, specially **Configuring the search widget** section. Also, because you're not using the `AppCompat` library, you should use this class (as declared in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#add-sv)):

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```